# Display all user informations with Spring Boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm creating a program with Spring Boot and I want display all user informations (I added first name, last name, city etc.) I can display user name by:

```html
<span sec:authentication="principal.username">
```

and now I want to display first name like this:

```html
<span sec:authentication="principal.FirstName">
```

This is code fragment:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
        
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("invalid username or password.");
    }
        
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
}
```

The question is what I suppose to add to be able to display all informations?

Answer (score 0):

If you *want/need* to use [the-authentication-tag](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/taglibs.html#the-authentication-tag),

> This tag allows access to the current Authentication object stored in the security context. It renders a property of the object directly in the JSP. So, for example, **if** the principal property of the Authentication is an instance of Spring Security’s UserDetails object, **then** using <sec:authentication property="principal.username" /> will render the name of the current user.

Then you should:

1. Subclass `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`/implement `UserDetails`. (`MyUserDetails`).
2. Enrich `MyUserDetails` (with `firstName`, `lastName`, etc.)
3. and return `MyUserDetails` instead of `new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(...)`
4. Then you can access any (custom) property like `<span sec:authentication="principal.firstName">` (`principal.foo`, `principal.bar`)

Even trickier, more greedy/efficient, if applicable:

Spare the `MyUserDetails` part and let your (persistent, `com.my.company...`) `User` *extend* `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` ... to return it directly (from db).

But as the documentation also states/people prefer:

> Of course, it isn’t necessary to use JSP tags for this kind of thing and some people prefer to keep as little logic as possible in the view. **You can access the Authentication object in your MVC controller (by calling SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()) and add the data directly to your model for rendering by the view.**

(in any conceivable manner)